# Eliminar la ultima coma de un foreach, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

como puedo eliminar la última coma de un foreach, pero estando en el controlador, ya que es la respuesta php de un AJAX.

```
<div class=\"lasOpt\">
   <div>
      <h5>Genero:</h5>
      <span>";
        foreach($pro->variaciones as $varia){
          if ($varia->variant == 'genero'){
            $filtradorHtml .= "$varia->valor, ";
          }
        }    
      $filtradorHtml .= 
       "</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Y aprovecho para preguntar, Si os dais cuenta antes del foreach, hay un `<h5>` con el titulo, hay alguna forma de que si `$varia->variant == 'genero'` existe si salga el titulo y si no existe no??

Gracias

**Edición**

He probado del siguiente modo lo de las comas y parace que funciona.

```
$dash   = '';
$string = ''; 
   foreach($pro->variaciones as $varia){
     if ($varia->variant == 'genero'){
       $string= $dash.$varia->valor;    
       $dash = ', ';
       $filtradorHtml .= "$string";
     }
}
```

Alguna ayuda para lo del titulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que lo almacenas en `$filtradorHtml`, puedes usar [substring](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) para eliminar los últimos dos caracteres (la coma y el espacio):

```
$filtradorHtml = substr($filtradorHtml, 0, -2);//Hace un substring desde el inicio (índice 0) hasta el final del string excepto los dos últimos elementos (-2)
```

En el enlace que te dejé a la documentación del método tienes más ejemplos si quieres

**Editado:**

Para añadir el título o no, puedes simplemente comprobar si el array contiene el valor deseado:

```
if(in_array("genero", array_values($pro->variaciones)){
    $filtradorHtml .= <h5>Genero:</h5>
}
```

Explicación:
El `if` será verdadero si el array que se le pasa a [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) contiene el valor "genero", como segundo parámetro dicha función necesita un array, obtenido usando [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php), el cual permite extraer todos los valores de un array de formato `["clave" => "valor"]`.

Si tienes alguna duda pregunta!

Comment: Estupendo @Benito-B funciona perfecto! alguna sugerencia con lo otro? gracias!